# How much one can save if they earn 2,500 Euros (tax excluded) per month in Dublin

Tags: europe, salary

How much one (single, not with family) can save if they earn 2,500 euros per month?

Consider that this amount is after excluding tax, If they live in minimalist lifestyle, shared house in Dublin.

Comment: This can only be opinion-based, as what one of us considers  a "minimalist style" isn't necessarily the same as what others think. I vote to close.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica minimalist style is nothing but living with only essence for day to day life (ignoring entertainment, pricey restaurants, party etc).

Comment: You can make a long list of things that you consider minimalist, but others will feel differently. Because others will feel differently, there can be no general case. Thus, all answers must be opinion-based. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on where in Dublin you live and what you consider to be a ‘minimalist lifestyle’. A single person monthly costs €820 without rent https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Dublin

Comment: Do you think a person can survive with 1000 € (including rent, and other expenses) in Dublin? Consider living in least expensive area in Dublin. So to save the remaining out of 2500€ ;) ?

Comment: @smc Likely not if you want to live in private. Possibly doable if you only need a room in a shared flat, but then only if "survive" means just "not starve to death".